# Execute couple command in cmd. Executed only one command

Tags: c#, cmd

Hellp. In my 'plumbing' I have 3 command that should performed sequentially, and each request must wait until the end of the previous command. Now I have done the 1st request, but 2nd and 3rd just skips... 
Could you please suggest how to change this 'plumbing'?

```
string strCmdText = s1;
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
   {
   FileName = "cmd.exe",
   RedirectStandardInput = true,
   RedirectStandardOutput = true,
   UseShellExecute = false,
   CreateNoWindow = true
   };

var process = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo };
process.Start();
process.StandardInput.WriteLine(strCmdText);
process.WaitForExit();

string strCmdText1 = s2;
process.StandardInput.WriteLine(strCmdText1);
process.WaitForExit();

string strCmdText2 = s3;
process.StandardInput.WriteLine(strCmdText2);
process.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
```

Thank you.

Comment: First, why do you go through cmd, and second, *what exactly* "doesn't work"?

Comment: Just checked your code and everything works like a charm.

Comment: When I write code that makes sense, it works fine. Note that in your example, you call `WaitForExit()` before you move on to writing new commands. When I try to do that, I never get to the next commands; it remains stuck on the call to `WaitForExit()`. If you want help, provide a good code example and a _specific_ description of what you are trying to do, what happens, and how that's different from what you want. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @PeterDuniho ok. sorry, that I had not provided an incomplete question. I have 3 command that should performed sequentially, and each request must wait until the end of the previous command. Now I have done the 1st request, but 2nd and 3rd just skips...

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski 1 - I have written 3 programms on python, which works with some data, I tested this programms just for one folder with data, now I need doing this actions with a lot of folders... This program execute via cmd..

Comment: @ie wierd... because in my situation, executed only one command..

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a problem description. If you don't understand why, call a home repair contractor and say "My plumbing doesn't work. Here's a picture of my house. What's wrong, and how much will it cost to fix it?" and see if you get an estimate without a lot more information.

Comment: It's not "advice". I'm explicitly telling you that you need to [edit] your question and make it more clear what the problem is you're having with the code you posted. "I have a problem" and "it doesn't work" are not things we can help you with unless you explain exactly what "doesn't work" means. If you want help, you need to clearly and specifically explain the problem.

Comment: @KenWhite. I hope this edits will help in my issue..

Answer (score 0):

Let's go through your code:

- You start an instance of `cmd.exe`:

  ```
  var process = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo };
  process.Start();
  ```
- You write a command to its standard input:

  ```
  process.StandardInput.WriteLine(strCmdText);
  ```
- And then you wait for `cmd.exe` to exit:

  ```
  process.WaitForExit();
  ```
- Now, you write another command to its standard input:

  ```
  string strCmdText1 = s2;
  process.StandardInput.WriteLine(strCmdText1);
  ```
- **Wait, *what?*** `cmd.exe` exited in the previous step, so there's no more process you could send a command to in the first place.
- Then you wait for the process to exit, but it's already dead a long time ago:

  ```
  process.WaitForExit();
  ```
- And you repeat the same non-working code:

  ```
  string strCmdText2 = s3;
  process.StandardInput.WriteLine(strCmdText2);
  process.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
  ```

You should better understand what's the the problem now. It looks like `cmd.exe` quits after executing your first command.

There's a couple things you can try:

- Get rid of `cmd.exe` altogether. Unless you execute some batch script you can directly call the intended executable (like `python.exe`).
- Start 3 different instances of `cmd.exe` for your 3 commands.
- Try to pass some arguments to `cmd.exe`, like `/Q`.

Try the first approach first, it's the cleanest one.